# Максимальное число соединений - это сколько пользователей сможет находиться на сайте одновременно?

Tags: c, сокет

```
struct sockaddr_in addr;
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_port = htons(atoi(port));
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ipv4);

if(bind(listener, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) != 0){
    return BIND_ERROR;
}
if(listen(listener, SOMAXCONN) != 0)
    return LISTEN_ERROR;
```

Пытаюсь понять как работают сокеты, для этого пишу свой сайт с бэком на си, есть функция `listen(listener, SOMAXCONN)` **SOMAXCONN = 128**. Правильно ли я понимаю, что максимальное число соединений - это сколько пользователей сможет находиться на сайте одновременно?

Comment: https://www.opennet.ru/docs/RUS/linux_base/node247.html

Comment: Подключи libuv. Не мучайся...

Comment: Нет. SOMAXCONN это количество запросов, ожидающих accept